# Netgear Wgr614v9 to extend WIFI range

Tags: wireless-router

I have a Linksys e3000 with DDWRT installed and is setup on the upper floor. The signals downstairs of house are quiet weak so I was wondering if I could use an old Netgear Wgr614v9 downstairs to work as a wireless repeater?